# WSO2 Creating Custom Widget by using Analytics Dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I try to create custom widget using analytics dashboard after entering widget name and pressing next, page become irresponsive.

[Sample page below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmRWF.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the Analytics version you are using?

Comment: My analytics version is 3.0.0. Besides my actual requirement, I want to see all my statics related to API Manager and Micro Integrator on a dashboard. Which product should I use (API-M Analytics or Streaming Integrator or any other stuff).